# Confused about meaning of SE and EX releases in cisco IOS

Tags: cisco, ios

I have been looking into this for a while now, but I can't find an explanation anywhere (the closest I could find was in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_IOS#Trains) and [cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/training-events/le21/le34/downloads/689/academy/2005/BRK-101.pdf) )
The switch is a 2960s that I need to stack to a 2960x (so I need the exact ios versions on both), I can download these two versions for the 2960S **15.0.2-EX5(ED)** and **15.0.2-SE10a(MD)**

Basically it seems to say that:

- **S** Consolidates mainline, E, and other S, which supports
  high-end backbone routers, and fixes defects.
- **E** Targets enterprise core and SP edge, supports
  advanced QoS, voice, security, and firewall, and fixes

But what means SE? It's a mix of S and E? What means the X in EX?

**UPDATED:**As @hertitu said in the comments, it's also important the release designation codes (list [here](https://www.cisco.com/public/library/iosplanner/reldesignation.html)), and the MD (manteinance deployment) means software more stable than the ED releases (Early Deployment)

Comment: Just found another person with the same question at cisco forums (no answer) https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12466021/2960s-ex-vs-se

Comment: Not sure if it helps much but "ED" is Early deployment and "MD" is Maintenance Deployment - see https://www.cisco.com/public/library/iosplanner/reldesignation.html

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but still useful, I'll update the question with the information you gave me @hertitu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the one/two letter designation is the branch/train/platform identifier.

Here is an old list of common branch identifiers:

- M/T – 800 Series ISR, ISRg2 (1900, 2900, 3900), Connected Grid Router 2000
- S – 7600 Series Router, ME 3600X, ME 3800X
- GC – 5900 Series Embedded Router
- SE – Catalyst 2960, 3560, 3750, IE 3000 Switches
- SG – Catalyst 4500E (Sup 6E and earlier)
- SY – Catalyst 6500E, 6807-XL, 6880
- EA – IE 2000 Switches

Reference:
https://www.packetmischief.ca/2013/12/09/ios-and-nx-os-platform-identifiers/

As you already identified, "*S*" could also be a consolidated release.  It is hard to say whether the "*SE*" is merely an identifier or whether it has deeper ties to the "*E*" releases.

"**X**" however in this case, most likely refers to an IOS "**Special Release**".  This is supported by the "ED" designation that you have already identified as "Early Deployment".

X Special Releases are defined as:

> **Special Releases**
>
> Are similar to rebuilds but instead of quick fixes, special releases
> introduce new features or additional platform support to quickly meet
> market demands.
>
> • A branch from a train code base.
>
> • Does not conform
> to a strict naming convention. They use a double letter after the
> release number.
>
> • The first letter could be a one-time release, the
> train identifier, or the technology identifier.
>
> • The second letter
> could be a sequential revision or a one-time release.
>
> • Special
> releases do not have an EoL, they are integrated back into the parent
> train.

This illustrates how Special Releases are integrated back into a parent train.
[image: Special Release Integration]

(Slides 15 and 18)
https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/training-events/le21/le34/downloads/689/academy/2005/BRK-101.pdf

The release notes from Cisco on IOS Release 15.0(2)EX call out the new features introduced in this special release.

> **What’s New in Cisco IOS Release 15.0(2)EX**
>
> First release of the Cisco Catalyst 2960-X Series Switches supporting
> two different feature sets:
>
> LAN Lite feature set—Provides standard
> Layer 2 security, quality of service (QoS), and up to 1024 active
> VLANs. LAN Lite models have reduced functionality and scalability with
> entry level features in layer 2 and provide no routing capability.
> They do not support stacking.
>
> LAN Base feature set—In addition to the
> LAN Lite feature set, the LAN Base feature set provides more advanced
> Layer 2 features, extended scalability, routing capability, and
> support for stacking with FlexStack-Plus.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960x/software/15-0_2_EX/release_notes/OL30810.html#pgfId-246822

Comment: thanks a lot, it's a pitty I can only give you a single upvote :)